# How set content frame using htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I need to set the content HTML within an iframe, as pictured.

[image: print]

1- Below, I get the frame. But the frame does not have a setContent
FrameWindow frame = page.getFrames().get(0);

2- So I got BaseFrameElement. But, how to put html code in content?
BaseFrameElement frame = page.getFrames().get(0).getFrameElement();
frame.setTextContent(textContent);

If you have a better solution, let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that i understand your problem. Usually some action on the page modifies the content of the iframe - there is no need to do this from the 'outside'.

Try something like

```
BaseFrameElement base = page.getFrames().get(0);
base.getEnclosedWindow().setEnclosedPage(newPage);
```

Keep in mind that this will not trigger all the events and might not have the result you expect.

Comment: `HtmlPage newPage = constructHtmlPage(browser, htmlPage);`   
`System.out.println(newPage.asXml());`   
**1- This worked.**   
    
`BaseFrameElement base = Page.getFrames().get(0).getFrameElement();`  
`base.getEnclosedWindow().setEnclosedPage(newPage);`  
`System.out.println(page.asXml());`  
**2- That did not work out. The newPage was not inserted in the iFrame, consequently, in the iFrame.**